# Create nested dictionaries with for loop in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have been trying create a dictionary that is made of dictionaries, while importing their values from a csv file.

Assume that I have 3 csv files, each for a different Rating (150,300,600) that are similar to this:

```
6,100
8,150
10,200
```

For each Rating, I am trying to populate a corresponding dictionary, like this:

```
Rating={150,300,600}
npd = {}
temp={}
flg={}
flg150={}
flg300={}
flg600={}

print(flg)
for k in Rating:
    print(k)
    reader=csv.reader(open(str(k)+'.csv'))
    for x in reader:
        key=x[0]
        temp[key]=x[1]
    print(temp) 
    flg[k]=temp
    print(flg[k])
print(flg)
```

I thought of creating one compound dictionary ie

> flg={150:{6:100,8:150,....},300{6:140,8:160...}, etc, etc}

and then assign the values to separate dictionaries:

> flg150=flg.get(150)

The problem is that when I run it, the flg dict ends up with the same value for all of its keys.

```
{}
600
{'8': '210', '6': '160', '10': '260'}
{'8': '210', '6': '160', '10': '260'}
300
{'8': '190', '6': '140', '10': '240'}
{'8': '190', '6': '140', '10': '240'}
150
{'8': '170', '6': '120', '10': '220'}
{'8': '170', '6': '120', '10': '220'}
{600: {'8': '170', '6': '120', '10': '220'}, 300: {'8': '170', '6': '120', '10': '220'}, 150: {'8': '170', '6': '120', '10': '220'}}
```

What am I doing wrong here? And is there a way to make this a bit more elegant, because it looks kind of ugly to me...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move `temp = {}` into your for-loop so that a new object is created every time you start reading a new file. Otherwise you're just reusing the same temp object so the values will be retained for each iteration.

```
for k in Rating:
    temp={}
    print(k)
    reader=csv.reader(open(str(k)+'.csv'))
    for x in reader:
        key=x[0]
        temp[key]=x[1]
    print(temp) 
    flg[k]=temp
    print(flg[k])
print(flg)
```

With each iteration you were updating the same temp dictionary. For key values within the temp dictionary, you were overwriting the values. For new key values, you were adding new items. In each case, you were printing the last value written so of course it was correct but you were overwriting the old entries. Try printing flg (not flg[k]) at the end of the loop for each iteration with the new code and the old code and compare the difference. What's happening should be obvious to you then

Comment: It works, but I can't say I fully understand the difference.When I printed flg[k] I would get the correct values. Could you please elaborate a bit more on the why it was wrong? Thanks so much for providing a solution!

Comment: Your output for flg was: {600: {'8': '170', '6': '120', '10': '220'}, 300: {'8': '170', '6': '120', '10': '220'}, 150: {'8': '170', '6': '120', '10': '220'}}. each sub entry has the same values. The reason is that you've got each key (150,300,600) set to the same temp dictionary.

Comment: I thought that flg[k] output was equal to temp each time (that's why it had the duplicate lines printed, called from print(temp) and print(flg[k])).So, in my mind flg[150] had the correct values assigned to it...I see what you mean now.Again thanks for the assistance.